# Get content from flickr

Tags: php

queria uma ajuda para pegar o conteúdo de uma página pela classe, ou seja, pegar todo o html dentro de uma div cuja a classe seja igual ao informado.

Abaixo está o que consegui fazer até o momento.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/esprit-confus/albums');
$curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
$html = curl_exec($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$albunsDiv = $xpath->query('//div[@class="view photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer"]')->item(0);
echo $album = $dom->saveXML($albunsDiv);
```

Comment: A principio não sei se o site deles permite esse tipo de captura de conteúdo, eu aconselho ler a documentação do API do Flickr:
**https://www.flickr.com/services/api/**

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não está funcionando pois você está utilizando `curl_setopt` como se fosse uma variável e não uma função nativa do *PHP*.

Você também **deve** fechar a conexão após `curl_exec`. E caso você não possua SSL no seu site, é necessário adicionar a opção `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` como `false`

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/esprit-confus/albums');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$albunsDiv = $xpath->query('//div[@class="view photo-list-view requiredToShowOnServer"]')->item(0);

/* Utilizando informações com Regex */
foreach($albunsDiv->childNodes as $child) {
    preg_match("/href=\"(?P<href>.*?)\".*title=\"(?P<title>.*?)\"/", $dom->saveXML($child), $content);

    echo "<a href=\"{$content["href"]}\">{$content["title"]}</a><br>";
}

/* Exibindo todo o conteúdo */
//echo $album = $dom->saveXML($albunsDiv);
```

Mas a depender do que você queira, talvez o melhor seja trabalhar com a API