# Tratamento de HTML co Guzzle Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Tenho um aplicação que precisa ler dados externos, ou seja de outra `URL`, estou fazendo isso necessariamente com `Guzzle`, porém quando converto para `json` para montar o array com os dados, o mesmo me retorna nulo.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;


class salarioController extends Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
     $client =  new Client();
     $response = $client->get('http://www.guiatrabalhista.com.br/guia/salario_minimo.htm');
     $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), TRUE);
  }
}
```

O resultado de `$body` é vazio.

Comment: Isso porque a função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) espera uma string *JSON* e você esta passando um documento *HTML*: `$response->getBody()`

Comment: O resultado daquele endereço é html, e o `json_decode` precisa de uma string no formato `json` **=>** `json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc ] )` realmente o resultado é nulo ...

Comment: Recomendo: [**https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277196/99718**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277196/99718) e também **[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277329/99718](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277329/99718)**

Comment: BLZ, vou tentar de outra forma, parece que tem outra biblioteca que trabalha em conjunto com Guzzle, a Goutte. vou tentar mais tarde , por hora muito obrigado pelos toques.

Comment: Bom dia pessoal, considere RESOLVIDO. utilizei guzzle + goutte porem necessita que  seja instalado o pacote php7.1-xml. funcionou PERFEITAMETE. Daí em diante é só tratar o array(). Muito obrigado pela força .. o código abaixo está CORRETO e FUNCIONANDO!!!!

Answer (score -1):

de momento tenho esse código usando Guzzle + Goutte, mas esta dando erro de :
"Class 'DOMDocument' not found"

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class ExtractController extends Controller
{

```
public function index(){

    $goutteClient = new Client();
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
                        'timeout' => 6000,));

    $goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);

    $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'http://www.cophieu68.vn/stockonline_node.php?stcid=1');

    $news = $crawler->filterXPath('//table[@id="board_online"]')->filter('tr')->each(function ($tr, $i) { return $tr->filter('td')->each(function ($td, $i) { return trim($td->text()); }); });

    return $news;
}
```

}