# Php Extraindo items de uma lista

Tags: php, html, libcurl

Galera como faço parar extrair os items de uma `<table>` usando php.?

a situação é a seguinte:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"url_onde_pego_os_dados");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
```

no caso $result é uma `<table>` com os items que quero extrair.

exemplo

```
<tr class="primeiroregistro">
             <td align="left">ABC</td>
             <td align="left">Atol ABC  </td>
             <td align="left">Plastico</td>
             <td align="right">13,45</td>
             <td align="right">13,01</td>
             <td align="right">13,65</td>
             <td align="right">13,27</td>
             <td align="right">13,28</td>
             <td align="right">-1,26%</td>
             <td align="right">13,25</td>
             <td align="right">13,28</td>
             <td align="right">1.368</td>
             <td align="right">506.500</td>
           </tr>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. O que é que tentaste até agora? Experimentas-te algum *parser* para XML/HTML? [É obrigatório salientar para não utilizar expressões regulares para HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Utilize `xpath`: [Exemplo 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277196/99718) **e** [Exemplo 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277387/99718)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o código a seguir na sua tabela para que você tenha uma fonte de disoaro para pegar a sua linha atual (a que for clicada).

```
<td>
   <button type="button"
           onclick="pegarEssaLinha(this)">
      Pegue esta Linha
   </button>
</td>
```

Agora no Javascript coloque esta função, pois ela será acionada ao clique do bo~tão lá da tabela.

```
function pegarEssaLinha(elemento) {
    // Linha atual
    var linhaAtual = $(elemento).closest("tr");
    // Celulas
    var coluna0 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim();

    window.alert(colunaID);
}
```

Note que o trecho onde tem >>> td:eq(0) <<< é a parte que pega o valor da primeira coluna do TD da Linha onde o botão foi acionado. Para pegar os demais valores troque o 0 pelo numero da coluna desejada.

Eu particularmente nunca utilizei estas funções do curl, então se eu fosse mandar para cadastrar mandaria via Ajax.

```
function pegarEssaLinha(elemento) {
   // Linha atual
   var linhaAtual = $(elemento).closest("tr");
   // Celulas
   var nParametros = {};
   nParametros.coluna0 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna1 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna2 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(2)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna3 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(3)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna4 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(4)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna5 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(5)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna6 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(6)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna7 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(7)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna8 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(8)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna9 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(9)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna10 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(10)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna11 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(11)").text().trim();
   nParametros.coluna12 = linhaAtual.find("td:eq(12)").text().trim();
   // Envia os dados para o servidor.
   $.post("url_onde_pego_os_dados", nParametros, function (resposta) {
       window.alert(resposta);
   });
}
```

Peque estes dados recuperando a super global $_POST["coluna0"] e assim por dia uma a uma lá no servidor.
Como não sei o que você que e precisa fazer, vou parar por aqui para não complicar demais.